# what am i missing to use embedded resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Asp.net with c# in Visual studios 2012. 
I added the images i need into the solution by

- Creating a folder
- rightclicking and selecting add-existing
- selected image file
- right clicked image - properties - build action embedded resource

I went into the project properties assembly info.cs and added references to my resources.

```
[assembly: WebResource("FIMS_Courses.Images.FIMSNext.gif", "image/gif")]
[assembly: WebResource("FIMS_Courses.Images.FIMSPrevious.gif", "image/gif")]
[assembly: WebResource("FIMS_Courses.Images.FIMSCourselist.gif", "image/gif")]
[assembly: WebResource("FIMS_Courses.Images.FIMStopofpage.gif", "image/gif")]
```

now i am trying to access them. 
Inside my asp potion of my program i select them by typing imageUrl= and then intellesense lets me choose the path; This is my code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PreviousListLink" ImageUrl="~/Images/FIMSCourselist.gif" CssClass="floatleft" runat="server"/> <asp:ImageButton ID="PreviousButtonTop" ImageUrl="~/Images/FIMSPrevious.gif" runat="server"/> &nbsp; <asp:ImageButton  ID="NextButtonTop" ImageUrl="~/Images/FIMSNext.gif" runat="server" />

<h4><asp:Label ID="CourseNumber" Text="####" runat="server"/> &nbsp; <asp:Label ID="CourseTitle" Text="This is a course Title" runat="server" /></h4>

<asp:Label id="Desc" text="Course Description" />
<a href="#TopOfPage"class="floatleft"><asp:Image ID="TopOfPageButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/FIMStopofpage.gif" runat="server" /></a>   <asp:ImageButton ID="PreviousButtonBottom" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />&nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="NextButtonBottom" ImageUrl=""  runat="server"/>
```

and when i give it a test run i get nothing showing up. no images what so ever. 
[image: No images Loaded]

am i missing some crucial steps to access embedded resources?

Comment: Did you try taking out the `~` to see if it works?  If not, where is the Images folder?  Off the root of you site?

Comment: No, The image folder is pre-compiled before it enters the site, it is connected with the c#/ asp.net code.  and the '~' was added by visual studios. i tried removing it and it did nothing.

Comment: I don't think you can reference them the way you are in the markup.  Try using code-behind to get a reference to the embedded image.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517173/cannot-access-embedded-resource-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your embedded resources using the code-behind.

Example:

```
string topOfPageImageUrl  = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(),
                       "FIMS_Courses.Images.FIMStopofpage.gif");
TopOfPageButton.ImageUrl = topOfPageImageUrl;
```